# How to serialize List<T> to XML Document.?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm not experienced in XML-serialization. I need to serialize System.Collections.Generic.List to XML document. I have the following classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public string Phone;
    public Int32 Score;
}

[Serializable()]
public class PersonOperation:Person
{
    public String City;
    public String OperationType;
    public DateTime OperationDate;
    public Decimal Amount;
    public Decimal AmountEUR;

    public void RoubleToEuro(CurrencyCode p_CurrencyCode, Decimal p_CurrencyRate)
    {
        if (p_CurrencyCode == CurrencyCode.Euro)
        {
            this.AmountEUR = Decimal.Round(Amount / p_CurrencyRate, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a collection of PersonOperation instances that I must serialize to XML.

```
private List<PersonOperation> _depositorsOperationsList = new List<PersonOperation>();
```

For XML serialization I try to use the following method:

```
public XmlDocument GetEntityXml<T>()
    {
        XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        XmlAttributes attr = new XmlAttributes();
        attr.XmlRoot = new XmlRootAttribute("Operation");
        overrides.Add(typeof(List<T>), attr);

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XPathNavigator nav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
        using (XmlWriter writer = nav.AppendChild())
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>), overrides);
            ser.Serialize(writer, _depositorsOperationsList);
        }
        return xmlDoc;
    }
```

I'm in need of the following XML-format after serialization:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1251" ?>
<Operation>
<PersonOperation>
    <Name>John Smith</Name>
    <Phone>79161234586</Phone>
    <City>Glasgow</City>    
    <Date>2014-02-03</Date>
    <OperationType>Join</OperationType>
    <Amount>9000.00</Amount>
    <AmountEUR>144.06</AmountEUR>
</PersonOperation>
<PersonOperation>
    <Name>Bill Satly</Name>
    <Phone>79163214569</Phone>
    <City>London</City>
    <Date>2014-07-10</Date>
    <OperationType>Join</OperationType>
    <Amount>9000.00</Amount>
    <AmountEUR>144.06</AmountEUR>
</PersonOperation>
. . . . . . . . . . .
<Operation>
```

But instead of this format I have the following one-line horror:

```
<Operation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><PersonOperation><Name>John Smith</Name><Phone>79161234586</Phone><Score>270</Score><City>Glasgow</City><OperationType>Join</OperationType><OperationDate>2014-02-03</OperationDate><Amount>9000.0000</Amount><AmountEUR>144.06</AmountEUR></PersonOperation><PersonOperation><Name>Bill Satly</Name><Phone>79163214569</Phone><Score>270</Score><City>London</City><OperationType>Join</OperationType><OperationDate>2014-07-10</OperationDate><Amount>9000.0000</Amount><AmountEUR>144.06</AmountEUR></PersonOperation></Operation>
```

How can I repair my GetEntityXml method for correct XML-format?

Comment: Your xml seems correct. What is wrong with it. (See `XmlWriter.Settings.Indent`)

Comment: single line xml is not "horrible", its in the exact correct format, it just doesn't look nice for people, which doesn't matter for serialization.

Comment: But format is wrong. I'm in need of the "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1251" ?>
<Operation>" in beginning of XML-document but in reality I have "<Operation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" in the beginning of XML-document.

Answer (score 1):

The `XmlWriter` has a `Settings` property of type `XmlWriterSettings`.
Try using that to specify the formatting to be used.

```
 using (XmlWriter writer = nav.AppendChild())
 {
     writer.Settings.Indent = true;
     XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>), overrides);
     ser.Serialize(writer, _depositorsOperationsList);
 }
```

More information here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbef2xz3(VS.80).aspx

Comment: System.Xml.XmlException has place if I add "writer.Settings.Indent = true" line;

Answer (score 0):

Just pasting snippet from my code that works fine..

```
Public Function ToXmlString() As String
    Dim builder = New StringBuilder()
    Dim xmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of T)), New XmlRootAttribute(_rootNodeName))
    Using writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, New XmlWriterSettings() With {.OmitXmlDeclaration = True})
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, _source)
    End Using
    Return builder.ToString()
End Function
```

---- Converted C# Code ----

```
public string ToXmlString()
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>), new XmlRootAttribute(_rootNodeName));
    using (writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true })) {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, _source);
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

where _rootNodeName is name of your root node of xml and _source is sourceList

And then to create XMLDoc from string --

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(xmlString);
```

Comment: Thank you very much but ToXmlString method needs to return XmlDocument type but not string type.

Comment: see added code, that will  change string to xmlDocument

Answer (score 0):

If you open your file with special XML editor or just with web navigator like chrome or internet explorer it will look like you want.

Comment: How to do that XML-document will begin from:   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1251" ?>
<Operation>
. . . . . . .